# add countries in directory_country_region magento2 table

Tags: magento2

I'm updating a custom plugin and I wish to add a country list in `directory_country_region` table.

First of all I edited my InstallSchema.php as here below:

```
/**
* Pre-existent code
*/

<?php
namespace Fattura24\AppFatturazione\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\WriterInterface;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    public function __construct
    (
        WriterInterface $configWriter
    )
    [... ] // Unmodified code

**/**
* NEW CODE
*/

public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
        {
            $setup->startSetup();
            if ($installer->tableExists('directory_country_region')) {
                $installer->getConnection()->addIndex(
                    $installer->getTable('directory_country_region'),
                    $setup->getIdxName(
                        $installer->getTable('directory_country_region'),
                        ['default_name'],
                        \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_FULLTEXT
                    ),
                    ['default_name'],
                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_FULLTEXT
                );
            }
            $setup->endSetup();
        }
    }
```

Then in the Setup directory I added an InstallData.php like that:

```
<?php

/**
 *
 * @Author            
 * @Date               
 * @Last modified by:   
 * @Last Modified time: 
 */

namespace Fattura24\AppFatturazione\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * Install Data
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
        $italian_regions = [
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'TO', 'default_name' => 'Torino'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'VC', 'default_name' => 'Vercelli'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'NO', 'default_name' => 'Novara'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'CN', 'default_name' => 'Cuneo'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'AT', 'default_name' => 'Asti'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'AL', 'default_name' => 'Alessandria'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'AO', 'default_name' => 'Aosta'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'IM', 'default_name' => 'Imperia'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'SV', 'default_name' => 'Savona'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'GE', 'default_name' => 'Genova'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'SP', 'default_name' => 'La Spezia'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'VA', 'default_name' => 'Varese'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'CO', 'default_name' => 'Como'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'SO', 'default_name' => 'Sondrio'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'MI', 'default_name' => 'Milano'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'BG', 'default_name' => 'Bergamo'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'BS', 'default_name' => 'Brescia'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'PV', 'default_name' => 'Pavia'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'CR', 'default_name' => 'Cremona'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'MN', 'default_name' => 'Mantova'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'BZ', 'default_name' => 'Bolzano/Bozen'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'TN', 'default_name' => 'Trento'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'VR', 'default_name' => 'Verona'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'VI', 'default_name' => 'Vicenza'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'BL', 'default_name' => 'Belluno'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'TV', 'default_name' => 'Treviso'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'VE', 'default_name' => 'Venezia'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'PD', 'default_name' => 'Padova'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'RO', 'default_name' => 'Rovigo'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'UD', 'default_name' => 'Udine'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'GO', 'default_name' => 'Gorizia'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'TS', 'default_name' => 'Trieste'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'PC', 'default_name' => 'Piacenza'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'PR', 'default_name' => 'Parma'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'RE', 'default_name' => 'Reggio nell\' Emilia'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'MO', 'default_name' => 'Modena'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'BO', 'default_name' => 'Bologna'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'FE', 'default_name' => 'Ferrara'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'RA', 'default_name' => 'Ravenna'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'FC', 'default_name' => 'Forlì-Cesena'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'PU', 'default_name' => 'Pesaro e Urbino'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'AN', 'default_name' => 'Ancona'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'MC', 'default_name' => 'Macerata'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'AP', 'default_name' => 'Ascoli Piceno'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'MS', 'default_name' => 'Massa-Carrara'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'LU', 'default_name' => 'Lucca'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'FI', 'default_name' => 'Firenze'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'LI', 'default_name' => 'Livorno'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'PI', 'default_name' => 'Pisa'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'AR', 'default_name' => 'Arezzo'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'SI', 'default_name' => 'Siena'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'GR', 'default_name' => 'Grosseto'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'PG', 'default_name' => 'Perugia'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'TR', 'default_name' => 'Terni'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'VT', 'default_name' => 'Viterbo'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'RI', 'default_name' => 'Rieti'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'RM', 'default_name' => 'Roma'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'LT', 'default_name' => 'Latina'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'FR', 'default_name' => 'Frosinone'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'CE', 'default_name' => 'Caserta'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'BN', 'default_name' => 'Benevento'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'NA', 'default_name' => 'Napoli'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'AV', 'default_name' => 'Avellino'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'SA', 'default_name' => 'Salerno'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'AQ', 'default_name' => 'L\' Aquila'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'TE', 'default_name' => 'Teramo'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'PE', 'default_name' => 'Pescara'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'CH', 'default_name' => 'Chieti'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'CB', 'default_name' => 'Campobasso'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'FG', 'default_name' => 'Foggia'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'BA', 'default_name' => 'Bari'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'BR', 'default_name' => 'Brindisi'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'LE', 'default_name' => 'Lecce'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'PZ', 'default_name' => 'Potenza'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'MT', 'default_name' => 'Matera'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'CS', 'default_name' => 'Cosenza'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'CZ', 'default_name' => 'Catanzaro'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'RC', 'default_name' => 'Reggio di Calabria'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'TP', 'default_name' => 'Trapani'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'PA', 'default_name' => 'Palermo'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'ME', 'default_name' => 'Messina'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'AG', 'default_name' => 'Agrigento'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'CL', 'default_name' => 'Caltanissetta'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'EN', 'default_name' => 'Enna'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'CT', 'default_name' => 'Catania'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'RG', 'default_name' => 'Ragusa'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'SR', 'default_name' => 'Siracusa'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'SS', 'default_name' => 'Sassari'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'NU', 'default_name' => 'Nuoro'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'CA', 'default_name' => 'Cagliari'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'PN', 'default_name' => 'Pordenone'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'IS', 'default_name' => 'Isernia'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'OR', 'default_name' => 'Oristano'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'BI', 'default_name' => 'Biella'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'LC', 'default_name' => 'Lecco'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'LO', 'default_name' => 'Lodi'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'RN', 'default_name' => 'Rimini'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'PO', 'default_name' => 'Prato'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'KR', 'default_name' => 'Crotone'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'VV', 'default_name' => 'Vibo Valentia'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'VB', 'default_name' => 'Verbano-Cusio-Ossola'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'OT', 'default_name' => 'Olbia-Tempio'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'OG', 'default_name' => 'Ogliastra'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'VS', 'default_name' => 'Medio Campidano'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'CI', 'default_name' => 'Carbonia-Iglesias'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'MB', 'default_name' => 'Monza e della Brianza'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'FM', 'default_name' => 'Fermo'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'BT', 'default_name' => 'Barletta-Andria-Trani'],
            ['country_id' => 'IT', 'code' => 'SU', 'default_name' => 'Sud Sardegna'],
        ];
        // insert the regions for Italy
        foreach ($italian_regions as $key => $value) {
            $select = $setup->getConnection()->select()
            ->from(['dcr' => $setup->getTable('directory_country_region')])
            ->where('dcr.country_id = ?', $value['country_id'])
            ->where('dcr.code = ?', $value['code'])
            ->where('dcr.default_name = ?', $value['default_name']);
            if (!$setup->getConnection()->fetchRow($select)) {
                $setup->getConnection()->insertForce(
                    $setup->getTable('directory_country_region'),
                    $value
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Eventually I typed `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`, then `php bin/magento cache:flush`, but when I check the db there is no new data in it. Any idea about the solution? Thanks

edit: here below my module.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Fattura24_AppFatturazione" setup_version="2.4.2"> </module>
</config>
```

in setup_module I have got the same version (2.4.2)

Comment: Could you please show you module.xml code and also show the version of your module in `setup_module` table of your database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I can see you have already installed your module. If your module is already installed then your InstallSchema.php & InstallData.php will not be executed. You have two options:

1. Put your changes in UpgradeSchema.php & Create UpgradeData.php file rather than InstallData.php. Make sure you update the version in your module.xml file to 2.4.3.
2. Simply Delete entry of your module from `setup_module` table and re-run the module. Since it wont file the installed module in table, it will execute InstallUpgrade.php & InstallData.php file. [But this is not recommended option].

Hope it finds helpfull